# File upload with slim: 301 in POST response

Tags: php, slim

I have problem with file upload. When trying to send file to my local server i get "301 Moved Permanently" as response for POST. No file is created in upload dir. Below is code for index.php and upload.html.
$base_url points to localhost/testpage

[index.php]

```
$app->get('/upload/', function() use ($app) {
    global $base_url;
    return $app->render('upload.html', array('base_url' => $base_url));
});

$app->post('/upload/', function() use ($app) {
    $imagename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $unique_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $filetype = strrchr($imgname, '.');
    $new_upload = 'upload' . $unique_id . $filetype;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_upload);
    //$the_upload = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_upload);
    //@chmod($new_upload, 0777);
    $app->redirect('/');
})
```

[upload.html]

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="{{base_url}}/upload" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="photo" value="" id="image" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload image" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?  You are sending a redirect after the file is uploaded: `$app->redirect('/');`

Comment: Yes, but it isn't redirected. It looks like $app->post('/upload/') is never run. It only reloads /upload page.

Comment: Check the result of `move_uploaded_file`, I think the path for `$new_upload` may not be writable or maybe needs a full path.  So are you or are you not getting a `301 Moved Permanently` response when uploading as stated in the question?

Comment: I do get 301 when checking with Firebug whats happening. After adding echo print_r($_FILES); die(); as first statement in $app->post('/upload') nothing happened.

Comment: Try changing your form tag to: `<form action="{{base_url}}/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`  You need that enctype if you want to send a file upload.

Comment: Problem was with action url. Should be "{{base_url}}/upload/"

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing 'photo' in the $_FILES array and not 'image'. The id field of input tag isn't sent in the form data, its only used by the browser.